# Calculate Count of users every month in Kusto query language

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a table named `tab1`:

```
Timestamp    Username.   sessionid
12-12-2020.  Ravi.       abc123
12-12-2020.  Hari.       oipio878
12-12-2020.  Ravi.       ytut987
11-12-2020.  Ram.        def123
10-12-2020.  Ravi.       jhgj54
10-12-2020.  Shiv.       qwee090
10-12-2020.  bob.        rtet4535
30-12-2020.  sita.       jgjye56
```

I want to count the number of distinct `Username`s per day, so that the output would be:

```
day.            count
10-12-2020.     3
11-12-2020.     1
12-12-2020.     2
30-12-2020.     1
```

Tried query:

```
tab1
    | where timestamp > datetime(01-08-2020)
    | range timestamp from datetime(01-08-2020) to now() step 1d
    | extend day = dayofmonth(timestamp)
    | distinct Username
    | count
| project day, count
```

Comment: The title says per month, but the description body and selected answer are bin by day. I suggest changing the question title to say "day" instead of "month".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a very close estimation of the number of Usernames per day, just run this (the number won't be accurate, see details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/dcount-aggfunction)):

```
tab1
| summarize dcount(Username) by bin(Timestamp, 1d)
```

If you want accurate results, then you should do this (just note that the query will be less performant than the previous one, and will only work if you have up to 1,000,000 usernames / day):

```
tab1
| summarize make_set(Username) by bin(Timestamp, 1d)
| project Timestamp, Count = array_length(set_Username)
```

Comment: I am new to KQL & this helped me. Thanks a lot :)

Along with this I am trying to get the percentage change in user count from previous month count to this month count.

month. count %change
10.      3            0%
11.      1           66.6%
12.      2           100%
Any suggestions on how to calculate this %change column?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Checkout the prev() function. BTW, please mark Slavik's answer as an answer if it was correct. Thanks much!

Comment: @ Avnera : Thanks for your help. Yes prev() worked.